# ffmpeg unable to initialize module windows 7 32 bit

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp

I have installed ffmpeg in window 7 32 bit in my php extension.When i start apache,i am getting message like   "PHp startup: ffmpeg: unable to initialize module"

My Xampp version: **2.5**
My php version  : **5.3.8.0**

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can anyone guide me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1.enter code here Go to [apachefriends.org](http://apachefriends.org) You will find a link to ffmpeg 0.6.0 for php 5.3.1 there.

2.Copy php_ffmpeg.dll to xampp\php\ext.

3.Copy ffmpeg.exe into root of your site or anywhere else as long you know where (you will have to define path to it in your php file)...

4.Copy everything else to windows/system32.

5.Add "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" or remove ";" on the beginning of that line in php.ini file (xampp\php\php.ini )

6.Restart apache server